# Line of sight dots on "chasm" map tile

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In Mansions of Madness:

On the map room ["chasm"](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1114631/mansions-of-madness?size=original) there are two spaces (The **Chasm** room is the lowest left tile). But only one of them has "line of sight dots". Does this mean that the other half (the one with the bridge) is not in line of sight from the "crypt" and "cave" rooms? So when I align them all in one straight line with the chasm at the end, I can shoot from the other end into the chasm piece, but nothing that is on the bridge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Chasm** room space with the bridge does not have line of sight to the room Crypt or Cave, because it does not have line of sight dots.

From the [rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/mansions-of-madness/support/MansionsOfMadnessLoRes.pdf) page 21 (**emphasis** mine).

> Note that monsters, investigators and feature markers do not block line of sight. Also note that **some spaces do not have line of sight dots**. A figure in one of these spaces has line of sight to every space in the room (and **does not have line of sight to other rooms**).

Answer (score 0):

**Both** spaces in the chasm have line of sight dots. The ones on the bridge space are next to the wooden poles that support the bridge.

Comment: Welcome to Boardgames.SE. We encourage answers that have evidence to back them up. Please post a picture of your **Chasm** room that has LOS dots on the "bridge side." If you examine the 1st Edition printing here lowest left tile, (BGG members can see the full 4751x3256 image), you cannot see LOS dots on the wooden bridge **space**, only on the rocky cliff side. http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1114631/mansions-of-madness